# JavaScript 'body onload=' fails to load function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a website for a school project which involves HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. For my website I decided to do a dice roll simulation which would calculate and then show dice images randomized. The problem is that the JavaScript portion of the code fails to work at all. The code in the load function which is supposed to change the text in the test paragraph doesn't execute, which makes me think that the problem is occuring with the onload part of the body tag. However, because I'm fairly new to JavaScript I'm not sure what the exact problem is or how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <script>
      function loadFunction() {
        document.getElementById('rolldice').onclick = rollDice;
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'works';
      }

      function rollDice() {
        var imgstrbase = 'diceimages/'
        var dicenum = document.getElementById('numselect').value;
        var dicetype = document.getElementById('diceselect').value;
        var die1val = randNum(dicetype);
        var die1imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(dice1val), '.jpg');
        if (dicenum >= 2) {
          var die2val = randNum(dicetype);
          var die2imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(dice2val), '.jpg');
          if (dicenum == 3) {
            var die3val = randNum(dicetype);
            var die3imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(dice3val), '.jpg');
          } else {
            var die3imgstr = 'diceimages/grey.jpg';
          }
        } else {
          var die2imgstr = 'diceimages/grey.jpg';
        }
        document.getElementById('die1img').src = die1imgstr;
        document.getElementById('die2img').src = die2imgstr;
        document.getElementById('die3img').src = die3imgstr;
      }

      function randNum(num) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * num) + 1;
      }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body onload='loadFunction();'>
    <p id='test'> original </p>
    <h1> Dice Roll! </h1>
    <form id='numselect'>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=1 checked> One <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=2> Two <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=3> Three <br>
      </form>
    <button id='rolldice' type='button'> Roll Dice </button>
    <form id='diceselect'>
      <input type='radio' name='list2' value='six' checked> Six-Sided <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list2' value='twenty'> Twenty-Sided <br>
      </form>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die1img'>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die2img'>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die3img'>
    </body>
</html>
```

For reference the dice images are called 'six1.jpg', 'six2.jpg', 'six3.jpg', 'six4.jpg', 'six5.jpg', and 'six6.jpg'. I haven't yet added the twenty-sided die images.

Comment: what is `dice1val`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('rolldice').onclick = rollDice();` The parenthesis are required

Answer (score 0):

Typo - die1val1 instead of dice1val1

```
var dice1val = randNum(dicetype);
```

should be

```
var die1val = randNum(dicetype);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <script>
      function loadFunction() {
        document.getElementById('rolldice').onclick = rollDice;
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'works';
      }

      function rollDice() {
        var imgstrbase = 'diceimages/'
        var dicenum = document.getElementById('numselect').value;
        var dicetype = document.getElementById('diceselect').value;
        var die1val = randNum(dicetype);
        var die1imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(die1val), '.jpg');
        if (dicenum >= 2) {
          var die2val = randNum(dicetype);
          var die2imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(die2val), '.jpg');
          if (dicenum == 3) {
            var die3val = randNum(dicetype);
            var die3imgstr = imgstrbase.concat(dicetype, String(die3val), '.jpg');
          } else {
            var die3imgstr = 'diceimages/grey.jpg';
          }
        } else {
          var die2imgstr = 'diceimages/grey.jpg';
        }
        document.getElementById('die1img').src = die1imgstr;
        document.getElementById('die2img').src = die2imgstr;
        document.getElementById('die3img').src = die3imgstr;
      }

      function randNum(num) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * num) + 1;
      }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body onload='loadFunction();'>
    <p id='test'> original </p>
    <h1> Dice Roll! </h1>
    <form id='numselect'>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=1 checked> One <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=2> Two <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list1' value=3> Three <br>
      </form>
    <button id='rolldice' type='button'> Roll Dice </button>
    <form id='diceselect'>
      <input type='radio' name='list2' value='six' checked> Six-Sided <br>
      <input type='radio' name='list2' value='twenty'> Twenty-Sided <br>
      </form>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die1img' alt='die1'>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die2img' alt = 'die2'>
    <img src='diceimages/grey.jpg' id='die3img' alt = 'die3'>
    </body>
</html>
```